# send mail google script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a google script that can send emails from google sheets.

I need to send emails to multiple students containing a licens for some software.

I have their emails in row a, their names in row b and the licens in row c.

I would like the email to say:

"Hi **STUDENT**

Here is your licens for some awesome software: **LICENS**

Best regards

Oliver"

I have been trying to find a similar script online, but havent been able to find something like this.

Maybe you have one like it or have seen it somewhere?

I have very poor coding skills.

Hope you guys can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below script

```
function sendMail() {
    var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var email = data[i][0];
        var username = data[i][1];
        var licens = data[i][2];
        var content = "<p>Hi " + username + "</p><p>Here is your licens for some awesome software: " + licens + "</p><p>Best regards,<br>Oliver</p>";
        MailApp.sendEmail({
            to: email,
            subject: "CUSTOM SUBJECT",
            htmlBody: content
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Works perfectly!